# Why does Attachments.Count return 0 on incoming mail with attachments?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to save attachments automatically to a local folder using Outlook 2010.

It works when I first create the rule and apply it to all inbox. It doesn't work with incoming mail (no file was saved).

I tried adding some weird code and it fired errors so the script ran.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "C:\temp"
Dim dateFormat As String
    dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
Next

End Sub
```

It seems that Outlook doesn't recognize the attachment for incoming mail. I tried adding "MsgBox MyMail.Attachments.Count" and it returned 0.

Comment: This is just function. How you call this function?

Comment: I added a rule in Outlook to call this function when new mails come.
I followed instruction from this site https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3747-outlook-auto-download-save-attachments-to-folder.html

Comment: Is this your first vba code on outlook?

Comment: Yes, it is.I just started using Outlook last week. I also have another function to save incoming mail's details to excel file and it works just fine.

Comment: I don't see any issues on your code, try deleting the rule and recreate- also make sure your macro security setting is okay to run your code

Comment: I tried it many times but nothing changes. No problem with macro security also. There seems to be some people with the same problem but I still haven't been able to find out any answer yet.

Comment: It seems that outlook just doesn't recognize the attachment for incoming mail. I tried adding "MsgBox MyMail.Attachments.Count" and it returned 0.

Answer (score 0):

*Replace your Outlook Rule with [Items.ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-itemadd-event-outlook) see example*

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        saveAttachtoDisk Item ' call sub
    End If
End Sub
```

> ***[Application.Startup Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869298.aspx)*** and **[Items.ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx)**
>
> ---
>
> *<sub>**[Items.ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx)** Occurs when one or more items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once. This event is not available in Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript).</sub>*
>
> ---
>
> *<sub>**[Application.Startup Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869298.aspx)** Occurs when Microsoft Outlook is starting, but after all add-in programs have been loaded.</sub>*
>
> ---

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the reason. It seems that using IMAP is not an option if I want to save attachments automatically. I switched to POP3 and everything works just fine.

Comment: You may mark this as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer