# Email `.body` empty but not empty when I first open the mail?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to do write a VBA script that takes the body of an incoming  email and sends it on to another person.

If I don't open the email the `.body` is empty and the email that is then sent is empty as well.

However when I open the email and then manually execute the script, it works and then `.body` isn't empty.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        ' default local Inbox
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test").Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
        Set Msg = item
        ' ******************
        Dim patternRef As String
        Dim patternDemandeur As String
        Dim patternNumero As String
        Dim patternDescriptionPanne As String
        Dim patternAdresse As String
        Dim patternDomaine As String
        Dim patternStatut As String
        Dim patternMotifDemande As String

        item.UnRead = False

        patternRef = "Numéro de la demande[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
        patternDemandeur = "Emetteur[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
        patternNumero = "N° tel de l'émetteur de la demande[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
        patternDescriptionPanne = "Commentaires initial[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
        patternAdresse = "Localisation de la demande[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
        patternDomaine = "Famille motif[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
        patternStatut = "Statut[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
        patternMotifDemande = "Motif de la demande[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"

        ' Creation des differentes variables récuperées dans l'émail de base        
        Dim sText As String 'Variable qui reprendra le corps de l'émail reçu.
        Dim xText As String 'Variable reférence de la demande.
        Dim yText As String 'Variable reférence du demandeur.
        Dim zText As String 'Variable reférence du numero de telephone.
        Dim dText As String 'Variable reférence de la description de la panne.
        Dim aText As String 'Variable reférence de l'adresse.
        Dim bText As String 'Variable reférence du domaine d'intervention.
        Dim cText As String 'Variable reférence du statut fournit par l'entreprise.
        Dim oText As String 'Variable reférence du motif de la demande.

        sText = Msg.Body ' affectation de la variable

        xText = TestRegExp(sText, patternRef, 0)
        yText = TestRegExp(sText, patternDemandeur, 0)
        zText = TestRegExp(sText, patternNumero, 0)
        dText = TestRegExp(sText, patternDescriptionPanne, 0)
        aText = TestRegExp(sText, patternAdresse, 0)
        aText = Left(aText, InStr(1, aText, "-") - 1) 'Permet de supprimer tout les charactères après le tiret. Garde dans le aText, du premier charactere au tiret -1 donc sans le tiret.
        oText = TestRegExp(sText, patternMotifDemande, 0)
        bText = TestRegExp(sText, patternDomaine, 1)
        cText = TestRegExp(sText, patternStatut, 0)

        Dim NewMail As MailItem ' nouvel email
        Dim obApp As Object
        Set obApp = Outlook.Application
        Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'ces 3 lignes creent le mail.

        With NewMail 'remplissage du mail
            .Subject = "Domain"
            .To = "email"

            .Body = "REF=" & xText & vbCrLf & "DOM=" & bText & vbCrLf & "OBJ=" & aText & vbCrLf & "DEMANDE D'INTERVENTION : " & oText & vbCrLf & dText & vbCrLf & "Appelant : " & yText & " / " & zText

            .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        End With

        NewMail.Send
    End If
End Sub

Function TestRegExp(myString As String, pattern As String, casDomaine As Integer)

    'Create objects.
    Dim objRegExp As RegExp
    Dim objMatch As Match
    Dim colMatches  As MatchCollection
    Dim RetStr As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim resultPrep As String

    ' Create a regular expression object.
    Set objRegExp = New RegExp

    'Set the pattern by  the Pattern property.
    objRegExp.pattern = pattern

    ' Set Case Insensitivity.
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

    'Set global applicability.
    objRegExp.Global = True

    'Test whether the String can be compared.
    If (objRegExp.Test(myString) = True) Then

        'Get the matches.
        Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(myString)   ' Execute search.

        If (objRegExp.Test(myString) = True) Then

            'Get the matches.
            Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(myString)   ' Execute search.
            For Each objMatch In colMatches   ' Iterate Matches collection.

                If casDomaine = 0 Then
                    result = objMatch.SubMatches(0)
                End If

                If casDomaine = 1 Then
                    'Idealement ne demander que si le texte contient un mot clé pour éviter les erreurs de typo. Resolu par utilisation de conditions, à tester avec Case
                    ' Select Case objMatch.SubMatches(0)

                    If trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Faible")) Then
                        ' "Electricité (C.Faible)"
                        result = "28"

                    ElseIf trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Fort")) Then
                        '  "Electricité (C.Fort)"
                        result = "27"

                    ElseIf trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Plomberie")) Or trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Sanitaire")) Then
                        ' "Plomberie / Sanitaire" / essayer d'eviter de lancer 2 cases (FaT)
                        result = "30"

                    ElseIf trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Clim")) Or trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Chauf")) Or trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Ventil")) Then
                        ' "Clim / Chauf / Ventil"
                        result = "24"

                    ElseIf trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Sécurité")) Or trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Incendie")) Then
                        ' "Sécurité / Incendie"
                        result = "32"

                    Else
                        result = "3"
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If

    TestRegExp = result

    'Affichage de chaque resultat pour la phase test
    ' MsgBox result // Affiche resultat à chaque fois pour les phases de test.

End Function


Function trouverMotDomaine(domaine As String, motCle As String) As Boolean

    Dim intPos As Integer
    intPos = 0
    intPos = InStr(domaine, motCle)
    trouverMotDomaine = intPos > 0

End Function
```

Comment: Is this all of your code?

Comment: No it's just the beginning but basically I set a variable like s = msg.body and it comes empty

Comment: Could you put in the full email code please? I would need to see it to know why it's not copying over.

Comment: When you say the email is empty do you mean absolutely empty or there is nothing after the = on each line?

Comment: I mean the body of the first mail is empty, sorry, so i have nothing after all the "="

Comment: For some setups, certain properties, do not become available until the item is displayed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49486970/1571407. Something like this could work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661919/outlook-run-script-rule-not-triggering-vba-script-for-incoming-messages. Apparently newer versions require `.Display`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46212678/getinspector-is-not-working-after-update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the .display message and then close .olDiscard immediately.

For more information, please see the following link:

[VBA Outlook 2010 received mail .Body is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348518/vba-outlook-2010-received-mail-body-is-empty)