# Outlook VBA to save attachment stopped working

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments, rules

Hi I've used the basic below script in a rule to save attachments to a folder that exists on my C:\ drive. It ran fine last week but now doesn't and I don't know what's changed.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\warre\Timesheets_IN"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

The rule setting searches for a particular phrase in the subject or body of the email on arrival, then runs the script.

I'm hoping it's something obvious.

I expected all attachments for the relevant emails to be saved in the specified folder. This script will save me an hour or two of work every Monday morning so would really appreciate the help.

Comment: `sSaveFolder` most likely needs a backslash at the end.

Comment: If the code worked, the environment may have changed. A possible cause and more reliable alternative. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483298/why-does-attachments-count-return-0-on-incoming-mail-with-attachments

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that your rule is run and script is called.

Then you can try to add a backslash at the end of folder path:

```
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & "\" & oAttachment.DisplayName
```

Or just try to change folder path string in the following way:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim sSaveFolder As String
  sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\warre\Timesheets_IN\"
  For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
  Next
End Sub
```

Be aware, the `DisplayName` property value can be the same for attachments in different emails, so the files can be simply overwritten when saved to the disk. Consider adding any IDs to the filename to make it unique. For example, you may consider using the `RecievedTime` property value to make the file name unique.